# Excel VBA Change Height and width of ListBox Programatically

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub add_ListBox()
Dim box As msforms.ListBox
Dim myBox As Object

For i = 0 To Select_Files.FileBox1.ListCount - 1
    Set box = UserForm4.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1", "tSourceBox" & i + 1, True)
    Set myBox = box

    With myBox
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "0 pt;189 pt"
        .IntegralHeight = True
        .Top = 24
        .Left = 6
        .Height = 153
        .Width = 189
    End With
Next


End Sub
```

The above code suddenly stopped working properly, and I don't understand why. Initially, it was producing the ListBoxes with the specified height and width. However, all of a sudden when I run the code height and width are not what is specified in the code.

How can I make it so that I have control over the height and width of the ListBoxes?

Excel 2010 Windows 7 x64

Comment: Are there any errors or it just does not work?

Comment: @MatthewD There are no errors. The ListBoxes appear, but their size is not what is specified in the code above. The ListBoxes are small squares; I believe they are the default height and width.

Comment: What if you try to set them after they are added? IE after the for loop to listboxname.height = 153

Comment: @MatthewD I'm at lunch at the moment, but will try that when I get back. I'm fairly certain that it still doesn't work correctly, as I thought that I ran the Sub without the for loop, and got the erroneously missized listboxes.

Comment: @MatthewD Thank you for your help. I thought I have found a solution. I had a call to this sub in the Initialize event of  a userform. After moving the sub call, to the Activate event, it now works properly.. At least for now.

Comment: Makes sense. I though it had something to do with the timing of creating them. Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ListBox property called `IntegralHeight` for ActiveX and Forms. Set it to `False`.